# Angular Ui grid non negative value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) v3.0.0-rc.22 in my apllication. I enabled edit feature using ui-grid-edit.

i use following in `columnDefs`

```
{displayName: 'Price', field: 'price', type: 'number', width: 70, aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum, },
```

How can i stop to insert negative value in this

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a plunker or jsfiddle project. I'm trying to see where you want the negative value to be input... Can you reword "How can i stop to insert negative value in this".

Comment: I trying say is : 
No one can insert negative value in price field.

Comment: Add an ng-model to the price column and add validation in your controller.

Comment: @BrianGerhards i try this http://plnkr.co/edit/SMRtoKgEtlP6th6IVXCp?p=preview

but not working

Answer (score 4):

In Ui-Grid, the editors are rendered using the ui-grid/cellEditor template. The default template does not have any validation as part of it. To add the validation, you can provide your own editableCellTemplate and provide min value to achieve your requirement.

```
editableCellTemplate :"<div><form name=\"inputForm\"><input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\" min=\"0\"></form></div>"
```

This is just a copy of the default template but with the min="0" added to avoid the negative numbers.

Look here for working sample ...

http://plnkr.co/edit/cHhiXYKflQMvnOI2C5lj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

simplest thing will be make input `type="number"` and `min="0"`

another way would be place and ng-model in the input and validate its values with ng-change.